# Is there a way to pass a form request to a custom request to validate data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to validate four forms in one controller in laravel, how do i pass the requests coming from different forms to my custom requests depends on the form.

```
if ( file_exists(base_path().'/App/'.$request->program_type.'.php')) {

   $formRequest = 'App\Http\Requests\\'.$request>program_type.'FormRequest';

      $validated = $formRequest::validate($request);
}


}
```

Comment: Post more detail about the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation).

You can specify different rules depending on the parameter sent in the form.
For example:

```
public function rules()
{
    $formType = $this->get('formType');
    if ($formType == 1) {
        $rules = $this->formOneRules();
    } elseif ($formType == 2) {
        $rules = $this->formTwoRules();
    } elseif ($formType == 2) {
        $rules = $this->formThreeRules();
    } else {
        $rules = $this->formFourRules();
    }

    return $rules;
}

private function formOneRules()
{
    return [
      //some rules
    ];
}

private function formTwoRules()
{
    return [
        //some rules
    ];
}

private function formThreeRules()
{
    return [
        //some rules
    ];
}

private function formFourRules()
{
    return [
        //some rules
    ];
}
```

So in your form, send some kind of parameter like `formType`.
Of course, instead of `if-else` you can use a `switch` statement.